# Genymotion Android - Only able to open one app, once. Getting blank screen on next app launch

Tags: android, virtual-machine, genymotion

**Edit:** It appears this issue is related to Android 4.2. Using a 4.1 (Galaxy Nexus 4 template) at the same resolution, the apps load normally.

I have Genymotion setup, running an Android VM. On each launch of the VM, I'm only able to launch one app, once. I can't even launch the same app twice in a row, or I'll get the blank screen.

For example, if I launch "Settings", it will load. But if I launch anything after that, I get a blank screen. This is requiring a VM reboot for every tiny change in code because I can't run my app twice in a row.

It appears the app runs (I have some startup logging that completes like normal), and I can "exit" back to the main Android screen from the blank screen so the VM is not hung.

- Genymotion 1.3.0 r20130924-0a6b309
- Android VM - Genymotion Galaxy
  S4/HTC One/Zperia Z - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 1080x1920
- Default settings
- Windows 7 64-bit
- Xeon X3333
- 2.66MhZ 8GB RAM
- NVidia GeForce 210

More info:

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.0, connecting the VM to ADB and selecting the running VM from the AVD Manager prompt when I build my app. I don't think the connection is the issue, since I can see it via ADB and load it up as expected at once per boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Genymotion [Galaxy Nexus - 4.1.1 - API 16 - 720x1280] image, then upping the resolution to 1080x1920 is a viable workaround.

Comment: How to change the resolution?

Comment: @Salman Simply click on settings icon next to device name on the list.

Answer (score 1):

After updating VirtualBox all problems have gone.